# While loop causes the computer to hang when the declaration of the variable is made outside the loop

Tags: php, while-loop

Unless the condition is true in the while loop, the code should print the content of the $user_login variable. This is fine if I declare the variable directly inside the loop. But can you help me understand why it hangs when the declaration is made outside? The code is below.

```
<?php
$logins = 'log/logins.txt'; // The login file
$file_handle = fopen($logins, 'r') or die('Can\'t open login records');
$user_login = fgets($file_handle);

// Now let's loop
echo '<ol>';
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
// When I put this $user_login variable outside the loop the computer hangs
// Otherwise the code works fine
// $user_login = fgets($file_handle);
    echo '<li>' . $user_login . '</li><br>';
}
echo '</ol><br>';
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Oh the error log. :) [03-Jul-2016 05:46:07] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\logins\index.php on line 40 - [03-Jul-2016 05:46:18 Asia/Manila] PHP Stack trace: - [03-Jul-2016 05:37:28 Asia/Manila] PHP   2. feof() C:\wamp\www\logins\index.php:35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the file pointer in the loop, otherwise the evaluation of the condition `!feof($file_handle)` will always return the same, and so your `while` loop will never exit.

That is why you need a line like this in the loop:

```
$user_login = fgets($file_handle);
```

This `fgets()` moves the file pointer forward, and at  a certain point it will reach the end of the file and make the `while` condition `false`.

Note that `$user_login` will get a different value in each iteration of the loop, when you have that line within the loop. It makes no sense to loop if you also don't get that new value. You would be producing the same `<li>` for ever and ever...

NB: there is no need to put `<br>` after a closing `</li>` or `</ol>` tag.

Comment: Hello I have a function to clean the data. Where should I put this function, should it be like this? $user_login = clean_data($user_login);// This is inside the loop, or, echo clean_data($user_login);.

Comment: Either will work. `echo clean_data($user_login);` is fine.